# How to create compound indices in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb

I do not know how to create compound indices in `pymongo`. In documentation (for example, [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html) and [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.8/tutorial.html)) I see only specific examples like:

```
>>> my_collection.create_index([("mike", pymongo.DESCENDING),
...                             ("eliot", pymongo.ASCENDING)])
```

or

```
>>> posts.create_index([("date", DESCENDING), ("author", ASCENDING)])
```

I do not get the reason - why to provide such specific examples right with `DESCENDING` and `ASCENDING` constants without giving any basic example - such as where we have, for example, two ordinary fields and want to have a compound index without any extra constraints and properties.

Comment: The syntax represents and "ordered dict" and the constants `DECENDING` and `ASCENDING` represent `-1` and `1` respectively. See [`.createIndex()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) in the core documentatio for a full explanation.

Comment: So, if I do not care about sorting while creating a compound index, I can use eihter `DESCENDING` or `ASCENDING` by default, since it does not really matter in my case?

Comment: What I'm asking is if there is some syntax like  `posts.create_index(["date","author"])`

Comment: It typically "does not matter" as the index format can traverse "forwards/backwards" with equal performance. The definition of "order" mostly matters to your "default" expected sort order.

Comment: To your last. No. You need to specify an "order" of indexation. It is required. As id the "ordered dict" concept, since index order of fields "is important" to a database like MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks! Your last comment explains everything.

Comment: It was actually my "first comment" if you read back.

Comment: I thought, you were speaking about the syntax of the given examples and not about the general case.